# How can I get an element's attribute from the parent's parent element's ID using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

So I have the following HTML...

**HTML:**

```
<div id="col1">
    <img src="1.jpg">
</div>
```

And I am implementing a HTML5 drag and drop feature where the inner html of `col1` is changed for the dragged element's inner html - so basically the columns change their content.

I have another div (let's call that `swap-text`) where I want to change its text content depending on what image is presently inside `col1`.

This is why I want to figure out how I can obtain `col1`'s `img` element's `src` attribute value through JavaScript so I can then write an `if` statement to change the content of the `swap-text` depending on which image is in `col1`.

I could add ID's to the `img` elements but then I still don't know how I would write the condition to check if say, `img-id1` parent is `col1`.

Attempt(s):

```
var doc = document.getElementById("col1");
var children = null;
var imgEle;

//gets img node, but also got 1/2 text object(s)?
for (var i = 0; i < doc.childNodes.length; i++) {
    children = doc.childNodes[i];
    console.log(children);
}

//document.getElementById("img")
//children[1].getAttribute('src'); - cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined 


//imgEle = doc.childNodes[0].getElementById('img'); - Object #<Text> has no method 'getElementById'

console.log(imgEle);
console.log(children);
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("col1").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This work fine pure javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("col1").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: This worked perfect, and kept in plain JavaScript form in the simplest way.
+rep to Passerby for the initial comment and thank you to rdonatoiop for the format editting.

Answer (score 1):

```
var doc = document.getElementById("col1");
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var imgParent = img.parentElement;
```

This is how you determine the elements parent/

Comment: Thank you for adding that in as well, great to know.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use JQuery so you can simply use:

```
$("img").attr("id"); //Return the id of the img element
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
var column = document.getElementById("col1");
var imgSrc = column.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src");
```

Or just use the jQuery - it's simpler:

```
$('#col1 img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

as you will only have one child node in col1 (the img), change the for loop.

```
var doc = document.getElementById("col1");
var children = null;
var imgEle;

//gets img node, but also got 1/2 text object(s)?
//for (var i = 0; i < doc.childNodes.length; i++) {
//    children = doc.childNodes[i];
//    console.log(children);
//}

childen = doc.childNodes[0];
// or children = doc.firstChild;

console.log(children);

//document.getElementById("img")
console.log(children.getAttribute('src')); - children is single object


//imgEle = doc.childNodes[0].getElementById('img'); - Object #<Text> has no method 'getElementById'

console.log(imgEle);
console.log(children);
```